# Validating UNC Paths (preventing \..\..\ and similar injections)

Tags: c#, security

What techniques should be used if building UNC paths dynamically, such that to constrain them to a particular root path.

```
string root = @"\\Blah\Share\YouStayHere\";

//pretend second string is from a query string a user could manipulate
string path = @"\\Blah\Share\YouStayHere\" + @"..\..\TresspassingQueryString";

if( ! SomeValidation(root, path) ) { throw new Exception("you dirty bastard"...
```

Granted this should probably be managed with permissions, but maybe the other directory is accessible in the context of another asp page within the same application so permissions wouldn't be an option.

I know the Request.MapPath can be used to keep access within the application's directory, but this is a share outside the virtual path of the .NET application.

I was hoping to use Path.Combine to resolve the path and then check to make sure that `pathCombined` begins with `root`, but Path.Combine will keep the ....\

Additionally, I imagine there might be other types of injections that someone could do in this situation, so I was hoping for something more generic than just doing a regex for "..\" tokens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath` to get the combined path with all the `\..\` removed.

Then check that the path still starts with the expected prefix.

You should put this in an exception handler (if an exception would cause a problem); `GetFullPath` will access the filesystem (for paths that exist) and if your nefarious client crafts a path that points at an inaccessible folder you'll get an exception.

Comment: I would probably also make sure that even if it is a valid path, but is trespassing outside the root, then I would make sure any error messages are ambiguous.  I.e. you don't want to have one message that has "This is an invalid path" and another error "This is a restricted area", because the second error message tells them that they guessed a real path, giving them information about the file structure.